# How can I change my URL address in the Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a Wordpress site and the URL of the site is "http://example.com/example/". I have used Wordpress themes and pages to set the website up. But now I want to change this URL to just show the homepage as "http://example.com" and the other site pages as "http://example.com/".

How can I achieve this in my WordPress site?

I want to change this URL to just show the homepage as "http://example.com" and the other site pages as "http://example.com/".

How can I achieve this in my WordPress site?

Comment: Where is your WP installation located? Is it in the root directory of the domain, or is `/example/` an actually existing sub-folder, that you put this in?

Comment: _"But now I want to change this URL to just show the homepage as `http://example.com` and the other site pages as `http://example.com/`"_ - that does not make sense, you can not have one and the same URL show the homepage, and also the individual sub-pages. (Unless you were to completely switch to POST requests for navigation purposes, which would be absolutely absurd to begin with; or used a frameset as a "wrapper" around the actual site.)

Comment: you need to move your wordpress installation to the root `/` directory of your webserver. There's plenty of tutorials on the web, this is one example: https://askwpgirl.com/move-wordpress-subdirectory-root/

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find what you need in the documentation,

https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/

On the Settings -> General screen in a single site installation of WordPress, there are two fields named “WordPress Address (URL)” and “Site Address (URL)”.
The “Site Address (URL)” setting is the address you want people to type in their browser to reach your WordPress blog.

Answer (score -1):

you can update wp-config.php with the values

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

Or update database by options table changes siteUrl and home to your address

Comment: This won't work, because the wordpress installation is most definitely located in a `/example/` subdirectory